# Compiled successfully in Eclipse, but fails using terminal

Tags: java, terminal

I'm trying to write Java programs in OOP style, and putting two files under the same folder called utility. Also the package is utility.

**HelloWorld.java**

```
package utility;

class HelloWorld {

    public void hello() {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }

}
```

**HelloWorldDriver.java**

```
package utility;

public class HelloWorldDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloWorld sayhello = new HelloWorld();
        sayhello.hello();
    }
}
```

I used Eclipse to run the `HelloWorldDriver.java`, which turned out a successful result.

> Hello, world!

However, as I was using terminal to run the programs, problems occurred. First, I use javac to compile all the .java files in the folder. Then, I run the file directly.

```
bash-3.2$ javac *.java
bash-3.2$ java HelloWorldDriver.java
```

However, the below problems occured.

```
HelloWorldDriver.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                HelloWorld sayhello = new HelloWorld();
                ^
  symbol:   class HelloWorld
  location: class HelloWorldDriver
HelloWorldDriver.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
                HelloWorld sayhello = new HelloWorld();
                                          ^
  symbol:   class HelloWorld
  location: class HelloWorldDriver
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

Please help suggest if there's anything wrong about the code or the way I use command lines.

Comment: No problem with your code, just that you forgot to add the classpath parameter

Comment: try adding the parameter `-cp .` on your `java` command

Comment: You don't run `.java` files: `java HelloWorldDriver`.

Comment: Thanks for the above comments. Eventually I do the below and ran the program successfully.
1. cd ..
2. java utility/HelloWorldDriver

Not sure why it works when I move back to the upper folder.

Comment: @AndyTurner you can "run" java files since `jdk-11`

Answer (score 0):

Two things here:

Your error is coming from the way you are trying to run your code in the command line. When you use the `java` command, you want to specify the compiled class file to run, instead of the java file to run. This would look something like `java myProgram.class` which is equivalent to `java myProgram`. Since you are referencing another file in your driver file, you need to add that to the class path so the Java runtime environment knows what to do when you ask it to run functions from that file. In your case, I believe the correct command to run would be `java HelloWorldDriver -cp HelloWorld`.

Another thing I'd like to mention is that inside your actual code, you don't actually need to create an instance of the HelloWorld class by doing `HelloWorld sayhello = new HelloWorld();`. Instead you could remove that line and change the line following it to `HelloWorld.hello()`. There are some instances where you would not want to do this, however for what you are doing, using `HelloWorld.hello()` will work just fine.